# Linear Algebra - Find the kernel of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

We have just started learning about kernels and I couldn't grasp an understanding of it forcing me to ask for a clear explanation on how to go about solving a question like:

Let $T: P_2 \to\mathbb R^3$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(a + bx+cx^2) = \begin{bmatrix}2a-b\\c-a\\a+b-3c\end{bmatrix}$. Find kernel of $T$.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What did you try, according to definition of kernel?

Answer (score 2):

The kernel of $T$, by definition consists of exactly those elements $f$ of $P_2$ such that $T(f)=0$.

So, basically the question is, for which coefficients $a,b,c$ (hence which -at most- quadratic *polynomials*) will we have 
$$\pmatrix{2a-b\\c-a\\a+b-3c}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0}\ ?$$

> And the answer is:
>  This vector equation holds iff the corresponding coordinates match, i.e. iff $\ 2a-b=0\ $ and $\ c-a=0\ $ and $\ a+b-3c=0$. The first two equation mean $2a=b$ and $c=a$, substituting these in the third gives $a+2a-3a=0$ which always holds.
>  So, an *arbitrary* $a\in\Bbb R\ $ (with $b=2a$ and $c=a$) will yield an element of $\ker T\subseteq P_2$, namely the polynomial $a+2ax+ax^2$, and these polynomials together form the kernel.